# Closing mdi child with esc

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to close an `mdi child` with <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. I tried using `keydown` and `keypress` events, but i cant even get  the form respond to those events when pressing any key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Property of the Form `KeyPreview=True`
and go with `Keydown Event`

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape){
   this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**or** make use of

[`Form.CancelButton Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) - Gets or sets the button control that is clicked when the user presses the ESC key.

Answer (score 2):

If your MDI Form has `Close` button, then you can assign `CancelButton` property with the ID of `Close` button in your Form.

So when you press <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, it will call `Close` button click.

More : [CancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

First you must set the `Form.KeyPreview = true` and you must know what is the Difference between the [KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) and [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) Event

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

and if you want the KeyPress Event

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 27)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```